# Silverlight 4: Application_Exit

Tags: web-services, silverlight-4.0, exit

How do I call a webservice in the Application_Exit event?

```
 private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestWSSoapClient.ReleaseUserCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(TestWSSoapClient_ReleaseUserCompleted);
        TestWSSoapClient.ReleaseUserAsync(UserToken);}
```

The method below is no longer executed.

```
void TestWSSoapClient_ReleaseUserCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can run it synchronously; or wait for the async to finish (which means stopping the current "exit", if that's even possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by following this [example](http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/Calling-Web-Services-from-Silverlight-after-the-Browser-has-closed.aspx)